# Spring controller mapping config

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I have little experience with configuring Spring and I'm having a hard time doing so. What I'm trying to do, is successfully map a url to a Controller using annotations. Furthermore, I'd like to have acces to the HttpRequest and optionally the HttpResponse. This is because I'd like to use Jackson to write and parse json directly to/from the bytestreams. Now I know Spring has JSON views using Jackson built in, but I'd like to get a decent foothold first as now I can't seem to get the mapping properly configured.

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>Kerris 2</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**app-confix.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="servlet" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

**DayController**

```
package servlet;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/days/*")
public class DayController {

    private DayDAO dayDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody void test(HttpResponse response){
         System.out.println("Days GET");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void test2(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response){
        System.out.println("Days POST");
    }

    public void setDaydao(DayDAO dayDao) {
        this.dayDao = dayDao;
        System.out.println("Days Dao assigned");
    }

}
```

When I look at my server log I can see the following lines in there

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/days/*] onto handler 'dayController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/days/*.*] onto handler 'dayController'
INFO: Mapped URL path [/days/*/] onto handler 'dayController'
```

Also when I test the application at *contextroot/* I see the standard Hello World! page. When I try *contextroot/days/* I get a 404. When I try *contextroot/days/test* also 404. Could anybody point me at what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I was doing wrong. As the n00b I am I didn't realize I have to specifically define a DispatcherServlet which hands the request over to the controller.

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**api-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="servlet" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

</beans>
```

When I try to call {contextroot}/api/days/ the request reaches the controller.